Working on a Homework Question I Encountered Before Taking the Course
This year, I have been studying ahead for some graduate math courses I will be taking in the fall. I have been working on some exercises from a classic textbook and discussing a few of them with a peer. Furthermore, occasionally, if I am very stuck I may read about the question or similar ones on StackExchange for some hints or to have a brief peek at an answer to give me some ideas (I may carefully read the first few lines and see some terms that stick out or some notation).
My question is: what should I do if I happen to encounter a question I have worked on when I self-studied the material in a homework assignment, especially for a question where I got some form of help either from a peer or StackExchange?
Would it be acceptable to answer the question, without looking at the answer I wrote before but also without attributing my (hypothetical) latest solution to help I received when I first did the question? Let's say at this point I only vaguely remember how I answered that question before and I reasoned through the steps of the problem without active assistance from those sources. I am wondering if I have any responsibility to make attributions at that point. I would definitely at least cite any sources that I actively used in my latest attempt at the problem.
I feel that the answer is complicated because it is possible to learn a common idea that was not one's own and then assimilate it into one's way of thinking. Even if one may not have originated the idea of using a technique for a certain problem, now they are aware of it and they use it according to their own understanding of what it does.
Now, if I am conscious that my answer to the homework question is heavily influenced by something I saw from, say, StackExchange in the past, to the point where it is not very much the product of my own thinking and is just reciting what I saw before, I would cite that.
As far as I can tell, this sort of situation likely occurs often with students and passes without acknowledgment because it almost never results in an answer that is too similar to a peer's or an answer from the internet. But I still wonder if there are pitfalls I should be aware of or if I am overthinking this.

Just how you learn to answer a question is not relevant. The test is to determine if you have learned to figure it out. That learning how to do it relied on a variety of sources doesn’t matter. Textbooks, lectures, office hours, tutors, friends - learning is learning.

I don't see any violation or any plagiarism (per se) unless you explicitly copy from another source without attribution.
Learning isn't about doing everything yourself without help. If it were, academics would be unemployable as irrelevant. The fact that you studied a topic before you took a course is to be admired. Instructors normally answer questions of students. It is part of the process. I favor minimal hints for such questions, but students often need help to work around a block. It is a natural part of learning.
And, I don't think you need to avoid what you wrote down before if it helps. The review will be helpful, as would attempting the solution again without review. But using them for "hints" only as necessary might be the best path.
If you want, though I wouldn't consider it necessary, you could add a note to any such homework answer that you have seen and solved this problem in the past with help.
Normally homework is to help you learn something and imprint ideas in your brain. It is usually graded as the carrot/stick to make you do it rather then just ignoring the potential benefits in the hope that you will "remember stuff". You have done that. Not a problem.
There was a time when students at a very prestigious university studying math wouldn't think about "taking" a course unless they had audited it first. Even if the questions asked in the second viewing were different, they had some idea about how to attack them.
Yes, you are overthinking it.

A slightly different approach: If you actually run into this situation, just reach out to the instructor and ask about their expectations.
There is a gray area and corresponding cultural expectations about whether some particular idea is "common knowledge" which vary by level in an academic environment.
When I teach students an introductory programming class, I instruct them to cite any StackOverflow questions and similar sources whose ideas they used to complete the assignment. But I don't expect most researchers to do that with boilerplate code in research software. Why? Adapting boilerplate is effectively common knowledge for experienced programmers, but is a substantial skill that I'm trying to teach at the introductory level.
I can't imagine caring about this for, e.g., a math class however, especially at the graduate level. If you've already seen an argument I thought it was important for you to think about, or already worked through the question before, or what have you...Great, I expect you to find something else productive to do with your time that furthers your career goals. One usually conveys and expects earlier graduate students to write more detailed proofs for introductory classes to exhibit that they understand what's going on, but that's at best tangential to worrying about plagiarism and citations. The grades already largely don't matter anyway.
